# Publishing error in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

[image]

Can any one help me on this issue why it is happening while publishing?

Comment: Have you done what the dialog suggests, i.e. either updated the form with InfoPath, or removed the custom form from the list? A bit more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you open the .xsn form from the workflow. If there's no customization of infopath form do the below:

- Delete the .xsn files from the designer (Bottom Right Corner)
- Publish the workflow

Your issue will be resolved.